# trouble with array push php

Tags: php, arrays

i want  to get multiple value of multi  array to put in one array 
i  creat this code but is doesn't work 
it just push the last value the full array
the result must be

$rest=Array ( [OPEN] => Array ( ), [HAPPY] => Array ( ) ,  [ALIVE] => Array ( ) ,[GOOD] => Array ( ) )

```
<?
error_reporting(0);
 $arr=array(
    0 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'understanding',
        'HAPPY' => 'great',
        'ALIVE' => 'playful',
        'GOOD' => 'calm'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'confident',
        'HAPPY' => 'gay',
        'ALIVE' => 'courageous',
        'GOOD' => 'peaceful'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'reliable',
        'HAPPY' => 'joyous',
        'ALIVE' => 'energetic',
        'GOOD' => 'at ease'
    ));
$feeling = array();
$x=0;
foreach ($arr[0] as $key => $value) {
$rest = array_merge($feeling,array("$key" => array()));
}
//$rest=Array ( [OPEN] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [HAPPY] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [ALIVE] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [GOOD] => Array ( ) )

 for ($i=0; $i <count($arr) ; $i++) { 

foreach ($arr[$i] as $key => $value) {
    array_push($rest[$key], $arr[$i][$key]);
}

 }
 print_r($rest);


?>
```

-----
    result what is give me 
    -----
    Array
    (
        [GOOD] => Array
            (
                [0] => calm
                [1] => peaceful
                [2] => at ease
            )

```
    [OPEN] =>
    [HAPPY] =>
    [ALIVE] =>
)
----
i want is like that
----
Array
(
    [GOOD] => Array
        (
            [0] => calm
            [1] => peaceful
            [2] => at ease
        )

    [OPEN] =>Array
        (
            [0] => understanding
            [1] => confident
            [2] => reliable
        )
    [HAPPY] =>Array
        (
            [0] => great
            [1] => gay
            [2] => joyous
        )
    [ALIVE] =>Array
        (
            [0] => playful
            [1] => courageous
            [2] => energetic
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is returning the desired output?

```
$arr=array(
    0 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'understanding',
        'HAPPY' => 'great',
        'ALIVE' => 'playful',
        'GOOD' => 'calm'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'confident',
        'HAPPY' => 'gay',
        'ALIVE' => 'courageous',
        'GOOD' => 'peaceful'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'reliable',
        'HAPPY' => 'joyous',
        'ALIVE' => 'energetic',
        'GOOD' => 'at ease'
    )
);


$output=array();
$keys=array_keys( $arr[0] );

for( $i=0; $i < count( $arr ); $i++ ){
    foreach( $keys as $key )$output[$key][]=$arr[$i][$key];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($output,true), '</pre>';
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [OPEN] => Array
        (
            [0] => understanding
            [1] => confident
            [2] => reliable
        )

    [HAPPY] => Array
        (
            [0] => great
            [1] => gay
            [2] => joyous
        )

    [ALIVE] => Array
        (
            [0] => playful
            [1] => courageous
            [2] => energetic
        )

    [GOOD] => Array
        (
            [0] => calm
            [1] => peaceful
            [2] => at ease
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understood your requirement then this solution will work for you.I used the `array_column()` approach because your current code with `for()` and `foreach()` loop seems little bit messy.

```
$arr=array(
    0 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'understanding',
        'HAPPY' => 'great',
        'ALIVE' => 'playful',
        'GOOD' => 'calm'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'confident',
        'HAPPY' => 'gay',
        'ALIVE' => 'courageous',
        'GOOD' => 'peaceful'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'OPEN' => 'reliable',
        'HAPPY' => 'joyous',
        'ALIVE' => 'energetic',
        'GOOD' => 'at ease'
    ));

$expected = [];
$keys = array_keys($arr[0]);
foreach($keys as $key){
   $expected[$key] = array_column($arr,$key);
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($expected);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

Array

```
(
    [OPEN] => Array
        (
            [0] => understanding
            [1] => confident
            [2] => reliable
        )

    [HAPPY] => Array
        (
            [0] => great
            [1] => gay
            [2] => joyous
        )

    [ALIVE] => Array
        (
            [0] => playful
            [1] => courageous
            [2] => energetic
        )

    [GOOD] => Array
        (
            [0] => calm
            [1] => peaceful
            [2] => at ease
        )

)
```